# Makefile: explicit entry works, wildcard % not working

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this rule in my makefile, but *make* didn't find it:

```
$(BUILDDIR)%.o : $(BUILDDIR)%.bin
    @echo
    $(OBJCOPY) -I binary -O elf32-avr --redefine-sym _binary_$*_bin_start=$* --redefine-sym _binary_$*_bin_end=$*_end $< $@
```

If I make it explicit, *make* will use them (called for build/rom1.o and build/rom2.o; BUILDDIR=build/)

```
$(BUILDDIR)rom1.o : $(BUILDDIR)rom1.bin
   @echo
   $(OBJCOPY) -I binary -O elf32-avr --redefine-sym _binary_rom1_bin_start=rom1 --redefine-sym _binary_rom1_bin_end=rom1_end $< $@

$(BUILDDIR)rom2.o : $(BUILDDIR)rom2.bin
   @echo
   $(OBJCOPY) -I binary -O elf32-avr --redefine-sym _binary_rom2_bin_start=rom2 --redefine-sym _binary_rom2_bin_end=rom2_end $< $@
```

Does anyone has a hint whats wrong with the wildcard in my first try?

**Edit:**
The version of make is 4.1 running on Ubuntu 16.04.
This is the error message from `make` when trying to run with the wildcard:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/rom1.o', needed by 'build/rom1.elf'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "make didn't find it".  What happened when you ran `make`?  Also, please be sure to specify what flavor and version of make you're using and (sometimes useful) what operating system you're using.

Comment: @MadScientist I've updated the post above

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see anything wrong in the parts of the makefile you've provided, so the issue must be somewhere else.  You'll need to run `make -d` (it will generate a lot of output) and look for the part where it tries to match the pattern rule and see why make decides to not match it.  I'm assuming that the `build/rom1.bin` file does exist.

Comment: This is the output trying to make rom1.o: [Pastbin](https://pastebin.com/4PREFuQ6). I added a target before that listing all files in the build folder: rom1.bin as well as rom2.bin does exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's simplify the problem…**

If this is your file structure…

```
.
├── Makefile
└── build
    ├── rom1.bin
    └── rom2.bin
```

and this is your Makefile…

```
BUILDDIR := build/

$(BUILDDIR)%.o: $(BUILDDIR)%.bin
    touch $@
```

and you run `$ make build/rom{1,2}.o`, your resulting file structure will be…

```
.
├── Makefile
└── build
    ├── rom1.bin
    ├── rom1.o
    ├── rom2.bin
    └── rom2.o
```